# How to deallocate extents of physical volume? lvm, encrypted

Tags: partition, encryption, xen, lvm

I just install Debian 8.1.
I allocated almost all disk 300 GiB to encrypted partition and a little bit for boot.
I want to make smaller 50GiB encrypted physical volume and install different xen OS to the free space.

Is it possible to do it without data loss? How?

---

System info:

```
/dev/dm-1 ext4 /
/dev/sda1 ext2 /boot
```

Files in /dev/mapper:

- `control`
- `hostname--vg-root`
- `hostname--vg-swap_1`
- `sda5_crypt`

---

Added the answer to the first comment:

```
root@X550C:/home/user# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0   243M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2            8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5            8:5    0 297.9G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt  254:0    0 297.9G  0 crypt 
    ├─hostname--vg-root
            254:1    0 290.1G  0 lvm   /
    └─hostname--vg-swap_1
            254:2    0   7.8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb               8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1            8:17   0 931.5G  0 part  /media/user/Seagate Backup     Plus Drive
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: The output of `lsblk` and `dmsetup table` would help. You mean the PV for the "hostname" VG is on a LUKS-encrypted sda5? Do you mean xen domain instead of xen OS?

Answer (score 4):

Reduce each of the pieces, from the inside out. You'll need to do that with `/` unmounted, so you'll need to do it from a live CD/USB. [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) is good at this kind of things. Note that you need fairly recent version of the LVM and `cryptsetup` tools.

1. Shrink the `/` filesystem with [`resize2fs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs).

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/mapper/hostname--vg-root 240G
   ```
2. Shrink the logical volume containing `/` with [`lvresize`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvresize). Make absolutely sure you don't shrink it below the size of the filesystem. Run `tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/hostname--vg-root` to double-check the filesystem size.

   ```
   lvresize -L 240g hostname/vg-root
   ```

   Note: if supported, tell `lvresize` to call [`fsadm`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsadm) to resize the filesystem. This eliminates the risk of accidentally shrinking the volume below the size of the filesystem. If this works, the previous step can be skipped.

   ```
   lvresize -r -L 240g hostname/vg-root
   ```
3. Shrink the physical volume `sda5_crypt` with [`pvresize`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pvresize). This may or may not work, due to a limitation of `pvresize`: if the logical volume happens to occupy some room near the end of the physical volume, `pvresize` won't move any data towards unoccupied space closer to the beginning of the volume. If you get bitten by that, the only solution I know of is to reduce the `/` filesystem and the logical volume as much as possible, and remove the swap volume, until you're able to shrink the physical volume to your content.

   ```
   pvresize --setphysicalvolume 248g /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt
   ```

   Then deactivate the volume group.

   ```
   vgchange -an hostname
   ```
4. Shrink the encrypted volume with [`cryptsetup`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup). Here again, make very sure not to shrink it below the size of the LVM physical volume. Note that the unit for the `--size` argument is 512-byte sectors. Very importantly, note that this is the size of the containing device, not the size of the encrypted data, so allow space for the metadata.

   ```
   cryptsetup resize --size $((248*2*1024*1024+4096)) sda5_crypt
   ```

   Then deactivate the encrypted volume.

   ```
   cryptsetup luksClose sda5_crypt
   ```
5. Shrink the partition with `fdisk`. Make sure not to shrink it below the size of the encrypted volume. You can create a new partition here.

Tip: if unsure about sizes, leave a margin at each step: shrink the inside more than the outside. Then, once everything is smaller than your goal, enlarge the encrypted volume to fill the partition, then enlarge the physical volume to fill the encrypted volume, then enlarge the logical volume to fill the physical volume, then enlarge the filesystem to fill the logical volume. Calling `cryptsetup resize`, `pvresize` and `resize2fs` without a size argument makes them fill the containing volume.